# Read file ics from active storage

Tags: ruby, icalendar, rails-activestorage

I would like to store a file .ics (Icalendar) through active storage. To read this file, I'm using the gem [Icalendar](https://github.com/icalendar/icalendar). Before, I was saving the file icalendar directly into my public folder like this :

```
require 'open-uri' 
dir = Rails.root.join('public', 'calendars')
file_name = "user_" + @user.id.to_s + "_calendar.ics"
File.write (dir+ file_name), open(@user.calendar_url).read.force_encoding("UTF-8")
```

To read the saved file, I was doing that :

```
pathname =  dir + file_name
@events = Icalendar::Event.parse(File.open(pathname))
```

.

**Now I would like to do the same with active storage**

This script was working great but I need to store this file through active_storage. For the first part (save the file), there is no problem :

```
@user.calendar.attach(io: open(@user.calendar_url), filename: 'calendar.ics')
```

But for the second part, read the file, I'm not able to read the file saved with active storage. I've tried many ways (like the followings) but without success

```
@events = Icalendar::Event.parse(@user.calendar)
@events = Icalendar::Event.parse(File.open(@user.calendar.service_url))
@events = Icalendar::Event.parse(File.open(Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(@user.calendar, only_path: true)))
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

File.open gives you a file reference. You want its content (File.read):

```
@events = Icalendar::Event.parse(File.read(@user.calendar.service_url))
```